# How to make a tab in Navigation bar auto-enabled?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Below is the html,css and Javascript code for a navigation bar.In this the content of each navigation bar is displayed only when we click on their respective icons(i.e. london,paris,tokyo), but I want the content of the first navigation bar to be displayed at first whenever the page is loaded. What changes can be made to the below code for this?
       HTML code:

```
<head>
<style>
#footer {
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
    clear:both;
    text-align:center;
    padding:5px;
     width:100%;
     align:center;

}

ul.tab {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    width: 90%;
}

ul.tab li {float: left;}

ul.tab li a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 17px;
}

ul.tab li a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

ul.tab li a:focus, .active {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

.tabcontent {
    display: none;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    -webkit-animation: fadeEffect 1s;
    animation: fadeEffect 1s;
    padding-left: 5%;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeEffect {
    from {opacity: 0;}
    to {opacity: 1;}
}

@keyframes fadeEffect {
    from {opacity: 0;}
    to {opacity: 1;}
}

</style>

<script>
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<center>
<ul class="tab">
  <li><a href="#" class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')">London</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</a></li>
</ul>
</center>
<br>
<br>
<div id="London" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>London</h3>
  London is the capital city of England.</p>

</div>

<div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Paris</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p>
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<div id="footer">
© Cities
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tab content loaded by default](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38583046/tab-content-loaded-by-default)

Comment: Is this a home work or something, how is it exactly same as : http://stackoverflow.com/q/38583046/3603806

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please search before create new question.
You can make your first tabcontent is display.May be inline html or in css:

```
.tabcontent:nth-of-type(1){display:block;}
```